# Método WaitHostQuiet do Attachmate - Extra! com python

Tags: python

Estou usando Python para automatizar o Attachmate - EXTRA!, assim como muitos fazem com VBA.

Estou usando o package *pywin32* encontrado [aqui](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32).

Estou seguindo a documentação do método `WaitHostQuiet` encontrado [aqui](http://docs.attachmate.com/extra/x-treme/apis/com/index.htm#waitforstreammethod_con.htm).

O problema ocorre quando tento definir um `SettleTime` para o método `WaitHostQuiet(SettleTime)`, conforme abaixo:

```
import win32com.client

system = win32com.client.Dispatch('EXTRA.System')
session = system.ActiveSession
screen = session.Screen
settletime = 1000    

screen.SendKeys('<Enter>')
if screen.WaitHostQuiet(settletime): # o erro acontece nessa linha
    print('yes')
```

Segue o texto do erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       screen.WaitHostQuiet(settletime)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py",
>   line 197, in **call**
>       return self._get_good_object_(self.*oleobj*.Invoke(*allArgs),self.*olerepr*.defaultDispatchName,None)
>
> com_error: (-2147352562, 'Número de parâmetros inválido.', None, None)

Porém, se eu não definir um `SettleTime`, funciona:

```
if screen.WaitHostQuiet(): # assim funciona
    print('yes')
```

Eu preciso definir o SettleTime, pois o valor padrão de 5 segundos é muito demorado para a minha aplicação e desejo utilizar um valor menor.

Quando escrevo o código em VBA tudo funciona:

```
Sub Teste()
    Dim system As Object, session As Object, screen As Object, settletime As Integer

    Set system = CreateObject("EXTRA.System")
    Set session = system.ActiveSession
    Set screen = session.screen
    settletime = 1000

    screen.SendKeys ("<Enter>")

    If screen.WaitHostQuiet(settletime) Then
        Debug.Print ("Yes")
    End If
End Sub
```

Alguém sabe o que pode estar causando o erro?

Answer (score -1):

Em vba eu uso desta forma para esperar um texto aparecer na tela, este objeto não retorno true/false ele apenas espera um determinado tempo

```
SUB ESPERAR_TEXTO(nLin as integer,nCol as integer,nTam as integer,sTexto as String)

    DO WHILE Sessao.Screen.OIA.xStatus = 5
        IF Trim(Sessao.Screen.GetString(nLin,nCol,nTam)) <> sTexto THEN
            Sessao.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(1000)
        END IF
    Loop


END SUB
```